# Error In MongoDB connection :Error in MongoDB connection:{ "name": "MongoNetworkError", "errorLabels": [ "TransientTransactionError" ] }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to open My MongoDB compass Database , I clicked on `connect`  button in the interface ; 
the interface doesnt lead me to my database ! While im running my project via my terminal in VCStudio ! it displayes this error !!

```
node app.js
(node:8840) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring 
engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the 
new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { 
useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server started at port : 3000
Error in MongoDB connection:{
"name": "MongoNetworkError",
"errorLabels": [
"TransientTransactionError"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was openning the cmd line and my integral terminal in VS code !! I kept only one , and I opened Task manager !! I launched MongoDB service ( I re-opened my MongoDB Compass Interface ) and the Database is been displayed correctly !!